# control a servo with android and arduino

Tags: android, bluetooth, controls, arduino

I'm trying to control a servo with an android phone and an arduino via bluetooth but the data in the arduino is received as a char, and the arduino doesn't know when all  the data is received and the servo don't move properly. The arduino code is this:
    #include

```
Servo myservo;

char val; // variable to receive data from the serial port
int ledpin = 13; // LED connected to pin 48 (on-board LED)

void setup() {

  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);  // pin 48 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT
  Serial.begin(9600);       // start serial communication at 9600bps
    myservo.attach(9);  
}

void loop() {

  if( Serial.available() )       // if data is available to read
  {
    val = Serial.read();         // read it and store it in 'val'
  }
   if( val - 0 >= 0 && val - 0 <= 180){
 }
   // Serial.print("Recibido");

  delay(100);                    // wait 100ms for next reading
}
```

What can I do to get the correct value from  "val" to  control the servo?

Comment: What is the expected range of `val`?  Is it 0 to 255 (an eight bit byte)?

Comment: @Robert Harvey  val is the position of the servo in degrees, I should subtract - '0' at any char to get the number but obviously the code is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple chars if you need them. Simple store each new char into an array and program your android program to send a specific byte that indicates the ending of the val reading.

Checking this "ending" byte each time you perform a read from serial will tell you if this char is to store or to convert the previous stored chars into an integer or whatever data type you need it.

Than simply converting that array will tell you the correct val.

Comment: Did you mean something like this:

Comment: Yes. Something like that. However you shouldnt use these while's. As you are stopping the loop method. Think of your loop () as an while that never ends. Keep in mind that subtracting zero to a char returns the current number as int ;)